# Is it possible to call external API's from within Rally

Tags: api, rally

Are there any current capabilities to call external API's from within Rally?

For instance, when a story is submitted, I want to gather some text from a text box and send it to an external GET API, then populate another rally text box field using the response from the API? (without going into source code)

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do that automatically in the tool, but we do have webhooks, so you could configure a hook for story creates as a GET to your api, and then in your api you could then call back into our web service api to set the text field on that item appropriately.

Docs for webhooks: https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/pigeon/docs/webhooks